# How can i create Test Suite report of SOAPUI using single Script Mentioned Format

Tags: reporting, soapui

I want to generate HTML report of SOAPUI test suite execution in the below format.

```
Project Name: BLA BLA
Total Test Cases : Executed 
NO of Test Cases Passed : Some No
No of Test Cases Failed : Some No
```

---

```
SRNO, Test Name ,Test Cases Description , Pass/Fail ,Errors if fail ,Date
BLA    BLA             BLA                   BLA           BLA        BLA
```

I am ok with Excel or HTML ,Need a single script which will run in after test suite execution

Comment: Question is broad, have a look at the [link](http://blog.infostretch.com/customizing-soapui-reports/) and then refine your question by editing it.

Comment: @Rao : This solution is not relevant

Comment: Sorry, incorrect link. See this one if applicable. http://code-dojo.blogspot.in/2015/02/run-soapui-project-using-ant-script.html

Comment: I am looking for Groovy Script for tear Down of Test suit , again above mentioned result not relevant ,thanks

Comment: It is recommented to use SoapUI's `testrunner` utility which is command line utility for executing the tests. And using `ant` will provide the flexibility to get the result in  `Junit-Html` report automatically in a standard format. Hence the link was referred and very much related.

Comment: @Rao : I want to create the customised report need very less data , report which get generated is not as per requirement . I way data asked above in that way or similar to that report should get generated

Comment: Of course, Junit style html report will have all the data that you mentioned.  If you are not satisfied with it, you may go ahead and write as you needed.

Comment: @Rao : i checked the JUNIT style report already that not required for US , thanks for helping out , I am looking for Groovy Script to generate

Comment: Please provide the solution i am stucked in middle